# How can I concatenate 3 columns into 1 using Excel and Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am working on a project in GIS software where I need to have a column containing dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD. Currently, in Excel I have 3 columns: 1 with the year, 1 with the month and 1 with the day. Looks like this:

```
|     A    |     B     |      C     |
|   2012   |     1     |      1     |
|   2012   |     2     |      1     |
|   2012   |     3     |      1     |
             ...etc...
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
|     A     |
| 2012-01-01|
| 2012-02-01|
| 2012-03-01|
```

I have several workbooks that I need in the same format so I figured that perhaps python would be a useful tool so that I didn't have to manually concatenate everything in Excel.

So, my question is, is there a simple way to not only concatenate these three columns, but to also add a zero in front of the month and day numbers?

I have been experimenting a little bit with the python library openpyxl, but have not come up with anything useful so far. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can use `.zfill(2)` to add a zero in front of months/days.

Comment: This easy to do with openpyxl. What have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be staying in excel, you may as well just use the excel macro scripting.  If your year, month, and day are in columns `A`, `B` and `C`, you can just type this in column `D` to concatenate them, then format it as a date and adjust the padding.

```
=$A1 & "-" & $B1 & "-" & $C1
```

Comment: Excel's datetime support is actually very poor. It could make a lot of sense to do the conversion to dates using something like Python.

Comment: @CharlieClark OP wants to stay in excel, so even if you do the string concatenation in python, the datetimes still need to live in excel

Comment: I think you're second guessing the OP who needs to provide more code. Especially if there are a lot of files it makes sense to do this without loading everything into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  def DateFromABC(self,ws):
    import datetime

    # Start reading from row 1
    for i,row in enumerate(ws.rows,1):
      sRow = str(i)
      # datetime goes into column 'D'
      Dcell = ws['D'+sRow]

      # Set datetime from 'ABC'
      Dcell.value = datetime.date(year=ws['A'+sRow].value,
                                  month=ws['B'+sRow].value,
                                  day=ws['C'+sRow].value
                                  )
      print('i=%s,tpye=%s, value=%s' % (i,str(type(Dcell.value)),Dcell.value ) )
    #end for
  #end def DateFromABC
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***